# Media source api source buffer append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, media-source

I am trying to stream "webm" video using media source api, I am following the demo code "http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html". I am not getting any errors but not playing.

here is my code

```
 var type=entry.type; // it is always "video/webm"

    var video=document.createElement("video");
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

 mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', function(e) {
    var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(type+';codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    var obj=get({path:entry.path,request:"read"}); // this is my server get
    obj.onstarted=function(url){
        self.showVideo(video,url);
    };
    obj.onBlobRecieved=function(chunk){
        //chunk is a blob               
        sourceBuffer.append(new Uint8Array(chunk));
    }
    obj.oncomplete=function(url){
        video.play(); // for testing play on complete

    }
  },false);
```

I was debugged code, sourcebuffer always returns length 0;

how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest chrome then dont use webkitsourceopen. Instead use sourceopen .  The prefixes have been disabled by defualt